Prove centre is inside cyclic quadrilateral with perpendicular diagonals
Let $ABCD$ be a convex cyclic quadrilateral, and the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ are perpendicular. The circumcircle of $ABCD$ has centre $O$.
I am trying to prove that the centre $O$ is inside $ABCD$.
I read here that

for an $n$−gon, if you look at the $n−1$ shortest sides and the total central angle is less than $180∘$,
then the center of the circle will not be in the $n$−.

For a cyclic quadrilateral with perpendicular diagonals, the total central angle of any 4-1 sides would be 270 degrees, so the centre would be inside the 4-gon/quadrilateral. However, I don't know how to prove this.
I also considered trying to prove that if $O$ is inside the quadrilateral when BD bisects AC (diagram here), when D is on top of C, and when D is on top of A, then O is inside ABCD wherever D is. When D is on top of A or C, a right angle triangle is formed, and O is on the hypotenuse (this is relatively easy to prove). Are these three sufficient? Am I even on the right track?

another example
Thanks in advance.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I believe that the "central angle" described by the previous question is an angle at the circumcentre $O$, not at the intersection $X$. So the total central angle of $3$ sides may be different from $270^\circ$.

If $AB$ is the largest side and the circumcenter is outside the quadrilateral, then $\angle ADB=\angle ACB>90°$.

@Intelligentipauca but how does that help prove the problem?

Because in your case $\angle ADB<90°$, hence...

@Intelligentipauca ohh I see; but how do I prove that ADB > 90 if the circumcenter is outside of the quadrilateral?
I read your profile description and im so sorry

First of all draw a sketch. If the circumcenter $O$ is outside quadrilateral $ABCD$, the central angle $AOB$ including $CD$ is less than.... and the central angle $AOB$ not including $CD$ is greater than...

Suppose by contradiction that center $O$ lies outside $ABCD$: if $AB$ is the largest side, then points $C$, $D$ lie on one side of line $AB$ while $O$ lies on the opposite side. That means that the arc $\alpha$ delimited by $AB$ and containing $C$ and $D$, is less than the other arc $\beta$ delimited by $AB$ and not containing $C$ and $D$. Hence $\beta>180°$.
Note that $\angle ADB$ and $\angle ACB$ are inscribed angles insisting upon $\beta$, hence:
$$\angle ADB=\angle ACB={\beta\over2}>90°.$$
But that is impossible, because $\angle ADB$ and $\angle ACB$ are interior angles of right triangles $ADX$ and $BCX$, respectively. That completes the proof.
